# Exporting data as .txt file from 8051 to PC

Tags: adc, 8051

I am trying to first convert an analog signal to a digital using an ADC and save those data in RAM, after that I want to export this data to PC as a .txt file to print the graph in MATLAB. My question is, how can I export the data as .txt file to my PC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go and read a little about serial connections...

Comment: Do you already have an ADC? An MCU, too? What's the setup you have now? Or is this "prospective" in the sense that you need to understand how it could happen if you had the right parts?

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this would be to use an RS232 peripheral to interface with the PC and let the PC record the data as a .txt file. Why? because an 8051 doesn't have that many resources to implement a filestream (it could be done) but it would be much better to use RS232 if you have the option.

Then use [realterm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/realterm/) to log it as a .txt file and import it into matlab